# Determining number of comments of facebook status

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How do I determine number of comments on a facebook status?

I thought of doing it through "stream" table. But I do not know how to query only status updates and not other posts through "stream" table.

I can't find a way to know "post_id" of "stream" table from "status_id" of "status" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to me/feed in the graph API.  In the feed (stream) item, there is a comments object.  In that comments object there will be a max of 2 comments shown, however, there is a comment count property that will tell you the total number of comments for that stream item.